# mongorestore out of memory

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

The mongo process has been killed by out of memory after import data from gz file (~1.75GB) to mongodb (docker container).

it used about 10GB of RAM. Tried to use with **--numParallelCollections** and **numInsertionWorkersPerCollection** but still not work.

```
mongorestore -u superAdmin -p 'password123321!' \
--numParallelCollections  1 \
--numInsertionWorkersPerCollection=1 \
--authenticationDatabase=admin --drop --db "logs" --gzip logs.bson.gz
```

Comment: Maybe unzip the file manually and import then.

Comment: Was it the mongod or mongorestore that was killed?

Comment: @Joe mongorestore was killed.